# How to rename column name in database using Zend Framework 2 doctrine?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a table named `Products` in which there is a column `id`. It has foreign key relationship with `prtyID` column in `ProductTypes` Table. I just want to change the column `id` of `Products` table to `prtyID`. How is it possible? Is there any doctrine command is available for that? Please help me to fix this..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here... `id` should be the primary id of `Products`, not a foreign key for another table. Please add your code if you ask a question.

Usually, Doctrine will use the property name to create the table column. So changing the property name to `$prtyId` would change your table column as well.

You can give every column the attribute "name" in the annotation of your entity, which will change the column name in your database:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="prtyID")
 **/
protected $id;
```

Or, because you don't define the foreign keys yourself in Doctrine but the association, you can define the association like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductTypes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="prtyID", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $type;
```

This will create the column "prtyID" in your products table which is defined as the foreign key to productTypes primary colum "id"